# MLCP input file path issue

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I have a delimited text file in my local machine and trying to load this file using MLCP into remotely located MarkLogic from my local machine. When I am doing this getting the below error msg. I didn't append '/' before my file path in my parameter but it is automatically appending slash to the path, which creating the issue.

> java.io.IOException: No input files found with the specified input
>   path file:/D:/MLCP Tool/test.txt and input file pattern .*    at
>   com.marklogic.contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.getSplits(FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.java:129)
>     at
>   com.marklogic.contentpump.DelimitedTextInputFormat.getSplits(DelimitedTextInputFormat.java:80)
>     at
>   com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:128)

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the MLCP command you are using as well.

Comment: Make sure that your path is specified correctly for the Windows environment: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/intro#id_66493

Comment: This is my MLCP command which i am calling from my java code [IMPORT, -host, HOST_NAME, -port, port-number, -username, USENAME, -password, PWD, -input_file_path, D:\MLCP Tool\test.txt, -input_file_type, delimited_text, -delimiter, |]

Comment: What version of MarkLogic? What version of MLCP?

Comment: MLCP version is 8.0 which i am using. Even i tried with 7.0 it didn't worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps modify your command as follows:

1) Add the **file:** scheme yourself to the input_file_path: file:D:\MLCP Tool\test.txt
2) Add the option **-mode local**

These are just to stop MLCP from making any assumptions on the way to handle the input file path.

If this does not work, try the command using mlcp.bat directly to try to isolate where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't seen the exact command you typed, but I've noticed that when you want to specify the delimiter, it's easier to work with an [options file](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/intro#id_36150). The fact that there's a space in the path could be a problem, although it doesn't appear to be what the error is complaining about.

Put this into a file, let's call it import.options:

```
import
-host
HOST_NAME
-port
port-number
-username
USERNAME
-password
PWD
-input_file_path
D:\MLCP Tool\test.txt
-input_file_type
delimited_text
-delimiter
|
```

Then call mlcp with the options file parameter:

```
mlcp.bat -options_file import.options
```